# checking a component is rendered without setting state in enzyme - using fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

i am trying to run a basic application, i am calling an api which is running in node layer. i am using proxy in package.json of react application, thats why i call fetch with relative url.

node is running in port 4000 and react is running in 3000.

so when i call api after success i will change the state of loading to false , initially  when api call request happens loader will come since loading is true after that DataComponent will come on success.

Basically initital loading will be false after response comes setting it to false to load DataComponent

Here i am not able to see the DataComponent, How can i check the DataComponent is rendered.

```js
// app.js

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    data: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async() => {
    const jsonRes = await fetch("/api/user");
    const data = await jsonRes.json();
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      data
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return ( <
        div className = "laoder-container" > < Loader / > < /div>
      )
    } else {
      return ( <
        DataComponent data = {
          this.state.data
        }
        />
      )
    }
  }
}


//app.test.js
import React from 'react'
import App from './App';
import {
  mount
} from 'enzyme'

describe('app.js', () => {
  it('should render the app component once data is there', () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({
          ok: true,
          json: function() {
            return {
              userName: 'John',
              surName: 'Doe'
            }
          }
        });
      });

      return p;
    });
  })

  const wrapper = mount( < App / > )
  expect(fetch).toBeCalled();
  wrapper.update();
  console.log(wrapper.debug()) // not showing the Data component

})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the fetch is happening asynchronously. By the time you call `wrapper.debug()` the state hasn't been able to update, because the `fetch` response has been put on the event stack. So the `fetch` *has been called*, but it hasn't returned any response.

You can see this by updating the test to something like this:

```js
// mock out fetch...
const wrapper = mount(<App />);
expect(fetch).toBeCalled();
setTimeout(() => {
  wrapper.update();
  console.log(wrapper.debug()); // should be showing the Data component now
}, 0);
```

That allows the promise callbacks to be called *before* trying to see the rendered markup by placing the update/debug code at the end of the event stack.

You could wrap that `setTimeout` in a promise to return from the `it` callback function, and place any `expects` inside of it before you `resolve` (otherwise it may never actually run the `expect` functions before the test ends).

```js
// mock out fetch...
const wrapper = mount(<App />);
expect(fetch).toBeCalled();
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    wrapper.update();
    console.log(wrapper.debug()); // should be showing the Data component now
    expect(...)
    resolve();
  }, 0);
});
```

---

An alternative would be to just test that the result of the data renders what you are expecting when the state has particular data:

```js
it("should render the app component once data is there", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  wrapper.setState({
    loading: false,
    data: {
      userName: "John",
      surName: "Doe"
    }
  });
  console.log(wrapper.debug()); // You'll see the DataComponent
});
```